# Why is there only the "moderator intervention" option when flagging an answer?

Tags: support

I came across an answer which is a NAA (it's a question on the same subject), but while I wanted to flag it as a NAA, only the "in need of moderator intervention" choice was proposed:

[image]

Is it normal? Why?

(I've searched but didn't found an answer on meta.)

Comment: The post has already been deleted while you were on the page. I'm sure there's a duplicate that addresses this, but I can't find it.

Comment: @CodeCaster you're right. I was sure to have refreshed the page before asking, I guess I didn't. Feel free to post your comment as an answer then.

Comment: Should I delete this question or should I let it be closed as duplicate?

Comment: Don't delete it, perhaps now people will find this one when searching for the same issue. :)